# Including embedded image as Toolboxbitmap

Tags: c#, visual-studio, controls, web-controls, toolbox

Common practice to show a image of control in visual studio toolbox includes embedding the image as a Resource. Instead i tried embedding the image file (`sidebar.png`) into a resource file `Resources.resx`. I don't have the lightest clue as to how i can set the image as toolboxbitmap. I tried below & no image appears, could you give me right thing to do here

```
[ToolboxBitmap(typeof(Sidebar),"sidebar")]
public class Sidebar : WebControl
```

where "sidebar" string represents the name of the image in the resx file that needs to be shown as a icon in visual studio toolbox.

note: All other posts details on how to include when the image is a embedded resource, not when inside a resource file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio toolbox images must be linked to your assembly as embedded resources, placing them in a resx/resources file is not currently supported.

Source: `GetBitmapFromResource()` method of the `System.Drawing.ToolboxBitmapAttribute` type (as of .NET 4.0).